# False positive with email regex

Tags: javascript

I'm using regex and match to grab all emails in an HTML string, however I'm getting false positives, how can I improve my regex (I'm not very good at it), I'd like to add something like "ends in .com" so I don't grab any false matches.

```
const emailRegex = /([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/ig;
let emailsInFacebook = bodyHTML.match(emailRegex);
```

This gives me an array with false positives like this one:

```
emails: 
{
  '0': 'badge-silver_es_ES@2x.jpg',
  '2': 'badge-silver_es_ES@2x-150x150.jpg',
  '3': 'info@grupomonico.com'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: It seems to me that these are all valid email addresses. Consider that `.jpg` could be a TLD (like`.com`) in the future and you don't want to have to change your regex when that happens. Instead of eliminating false positives, you might use a verification email to check that the user entered the correct address. You should be more worried about false negatives, like how your regex doesn't allow foo+bar@example.com even though it's valid.